# Recommendations for deep sea hydrophone calibration - US West Coast

Tags: calibration, hydrophone, acoustic-monitoring

I would like recommendations of where to get 7 deep-sea hydrophones fully calibrated. Units are SonoValuts (purchased new from Develogic) and the hydrophones are Neptune D/60. Recorders were individually calibrated before purchase but hydrophones only batch calibrated. So would like to get hydrophones (with or without recorders) fully calibrated.

Ideally this would be west coast US but any part of US would be ok. I am aware of the US Navy
TRANSDEC facility that would be ideal to use - however as a commercial organisation we would require a Service Agreement that takes 6 months to set up. We have also tried NOAA Fisheries department and California Department of Fish and Wildlife, Marine Region. Any recommendations for commercial or research organisations offering full calibration of deep-sea hydrophones very much appreciated.

Comment: Hi John, welcome! It might be helpful to include what applications you would be using the hydrophones for?

Comment: Are you willing to carry out the calibration yourself?

Comment: Ideally, we would send them to a facility/lab to get calibrated by the labs and sent back. It is not possible to conduct the actual calibration ourselves.

Comment: Are you wanting a full-spectrum calibration (e.g. every 10 kHz or whatever)? Or just at a specific frequency. If you can't find a facility and don't want to do it yourself in a calibration tank, the easiest thing would be to use a pistonphone and DIY on the bench.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered reaching out to an acoustics-specialised consultancy? (e.g. [JASCO applied science](https://www.jasco.com/)s, [SMRU Consulting](https://www.smruconsulting.com/) North America, [Greeneridge sciences](https://www.greeneridge.com/en/) inc.?